# Java - Storing a "score" from play to play

Tags: java

I wish to be able to keep a score that a player gets when playing my game from game to game and to when they close the game and re-open the scores are still saved. The only way I can think of is to do so using a text file, like I would of done in VB6. However, that then means that they can edit the text file? Or not? My score is stored in a "double" that can be accessed from any class and is being transferred around classes as it is, if that makes a difference.

Hope someone can suggest the best way to go about this.

Comment: Are you asking about how to solve the problem in JAVA ?? If that so, did you have a look into the Collection framework in java ?

Comment: Does this game have a GUI?  If so it can be launched using JWS & use the persistence service.  It is not easily accessible to the end user.

Comment: @Swagatika I am looking at it now. Andrew It does have a basic GUI yes, and I will look in to what you have said now. Thank you both

Comment: Note that I do not get notified of your comments unless they start with @Andrew.  I just popped back to check on this thread!

Comment: @AndrewThompson It said that I could only tag one person. In hindsight I should of just made two comments

Comment: Spot on.  That's what it is telling you.  ;)  (and if you are wondering why I don't need to @Kyle93, that is a longer story..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If keeping the score secret and non editable is very important, I suggest you either store the score on of all players a secure server that only you control, or if that is outside the scope of your project, use an encryption method and also store the score as binary data (i.e. store your gamestate object, not the score itself) instead of a text file.

Comment: I am thinking of going with the sever method, as they have not put any restrictions on this sort of thing. So as I have a server I can use I will try and use that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Any app. that has a GUI can be launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) & use the [`PersistenceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/PersistenceService.html). Data in the persistence service is not easily accessible to the end user.  Here is a small [demo. of the persistence service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

As to how to store the data, If it is not absolutely vital to prevent the user from altering it, I would use a `Properties` object or XML/POJO.

If it **is** very important (e.g. gamers competing for a $10,000 prize), encrypt the values, then go with the remote server, encrypted (etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the file using one way or another, so it will not be easily editable (and editing attempts may corrupt the score at all, consequently.) [Here](http://www.example-code.com/java/aes_stringEncryption.asp) is a simple example of AES string encryption.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and use this in combination with storing the file on a server

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? It seems to be some kind of homework for me.

You can read and write Files with Java. You can also do object-serialization or use an embedded database.

**update:**
I would suggest to store all information within a database at the server. There are many way to do this. The concrete implementation would depend in your backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the file on the local machine, obviously every user that have read/write permissions on that file could modify it.

I suggest you to follow one of these ways

1. Encrypt the file and decrpyt it on open
2. Save it onto a remote file onto a server
3. Use a DB

Comment: Exactly what my issue is, I am trying to think of a way to not have them be able to edit it. I am thinking about the encrypt and decrypt method

Comment: @Kyle93 If you mix encryption with delocate file onto a server, i think you'll be able to keep a good level of security (if you only store it locally, someone could be able to delete it)

Comment: Got it, so if I was able to store a text file on a sever that was then edited using normal methods the player would not be able to edit that file. Cheers